# Scrolling a div with a header but keeping it fixed at 20px top when header disappears

Tags: css, css-position

I want to display a notification on a page with a header, like this:

```
+-------------------------------+
| header                        |
+-------------------------------+
|                [notification] |
| first line of my text         |
|    second line of my text     |
:                               :
```

However when I scroll down, the notification should scroll with the page below the header, but up to the minimum where its `top` is at `20px`. So when we're scrolling, the viewport should stay like this:

```
| header                        |
+-------------------------------+
|                [notification] |
| first line of my text         |
|    second line of my text     |
:                               :
```

But eventually when the header starts to disappear from the page, I am fine with the notification appearing atop of my text, with its `top` at `20px`:

```
+-------------------------------+
|                [notification] |
| first line of my text         |
|    second line of my text     |
|       third line of my text   |
:                               :
```

And with further scrolling:

```
| first line of m[notification] |
|    second line of my text     |
|       third line of my text   |
|           fourth line of my t |
:                               :
```

So basically want to display a `display: fixed;` div with `top: 20px` *except* when the page is on top.

So when I first see the page its `top` property should be at `60px`. However if I scroll down, I want it to have its `top` constantly at `20px`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use some basic js, try jquery if you need to support ie!

solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/beGtq

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of documentation, here are the snippets on Paranoid42's answer, which I am accepting:

**CSS**

```
.header {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #3e8a94;
}

.notification {
  position: fixed;
  height: 20px;
  right: 10px;
  background-color: #3e55c7;
  top: 50px;
}
.content {
  padding:40px;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 1000px;
  border: 2px solid  #666;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function() {
  if ( document.body.scrollTop > 50 ) {
    document.querySelector('.notification').style.top = '0px';
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.notification').style.top = '50px';
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="notification">  notification</div>
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content"><p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ..... </p></div>
  </body>
</html>
```